# Initial size of mutable Hashmap in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

As in Java, whenever we declare a map like

```
Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap();
```

then a hashtable of size 16 is created initially with a load factor of 0.75.

Similarly, what will be the initial size and load factor of scala mutable hashmap ?
Will be similar to java wherein a hashtable of default size of 16 is created ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's the same with Java `HashMap` where initial size is `16` and load factor of `75%`. They're all defined as per [scala.collection.mutable.HashTable](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/6ff3facb1791f54ad10fbf44059d892e5fd00510/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/HashTable.scala).

```
private[collection] final def defaultLoadFactor: Int = 750 // corresponds to 75%
...
protected def initialSize: Int = 16
```